# how to match pattern from one dataframe on 2nd df in scala

Tags: scala

I have 2 data frame in Scala

```
1DF=all proxy url(url,ip)
2Df=regex list(patten,type)
```

I want to extract `uuid` or credit card id from `url` using list `2df` ..and Store the matched pattern record along with it's IP address and the URL. please give me solution

Comment: Add some code which you have tried so far?

Comment: How large is `2Df` - is it relatively small (i.e. can fit in Driver application's memory) or could it be too large for that?